# Translation Golf XLVIII — We're sorry to see you go

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

**Game over, *amigos*!**

OK, this edition has been kind of an emotional roller-coaster for many of us (to put it *really* lightly) **and** the source of many a headache for mods, CMs and veteran users alike... but in the end I think we got some nicely golfed translations worth of praise!

[user2325442's](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31617),  [user0721090601's](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31616), [Luis Rico's](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31641), [Peter Taylor's](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31629) and  [user23391's](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31642) answers all got the original text down to about ~70 chars or less, an 80-90% reduction in length which is honestly impressive!
On the other hand, not all of them managed to keep the original concepts in the translation to the same degree, and that is important too.

All things considered, I think one of the answers managed to strike the best balance between shortness and closeness to the original -- and that is **[Luis Ricos's answer with 66 chars](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31641). Congratulations, Luis Rico! We're happy to see you win :)**

As per TG rules, as the winner, Luis Rico has now two days to propose a new text for the next edition of the game, if they want to. After two days, anybody can post a new TG question with a new text for everybody to have fun :)
See you then!

---

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This week's text is taken from what looks like a [standard](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1650/i-am-resigning-as-a-moderator/1654#1654) [canned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites-effective-today/389908#389908) [response](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel/5197#5197):

> We understand there are some folks upset about the decision made this week. We aren’t going to share specifics out of respect for all individuals involved but this is a site reaching millions of people and we have to do what we believe fosters a spirit of inclusion and respect. When a moderator violates that, we will always do our best to resolve it with them privately. When we can’t we must take action. This is always done based on what we believe is best for all SE users.
>
> <sub>(382 characters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

My own, non-golfed translation:

> Comprendemos que hay algunos paisanos molestos por la decisión tomada esta semana. No vamos a compartir los detalles por respeto a todos los individuos implicados pero esto es un sitio que alcanza a millones de personas y tenemos que hacer aquello que creemos que fomenta un espíritu de inclusión y respeto. Cuando un moderador viola eso, siempre haremos lo mejor posible para solucionarlo con ellos en privado. Cuando no podemos debemos tomar medidas. Esto siempre se hace basado en lo que creemos que es lo mejor para todos los usuarios de SE.
>
>  <sub>(448 characters)</sub>

---

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481).

  - Special rule for this edition: OP can participate, too.
- Letter counter (only letters and numbers matter): [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contestants? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: Comments should be for requesting clarification from the author. I know this question has opened some debate and controversy. Everyone is free to vote this question to be closed (provided they have the needed rep points), so let's keep this comment section strictly professional.

Comment: I am unable to raise a flag on this question, because I already have one pending, that I raised when the question first appeared.  My new flag is different.  I will attempt to raise it here instead, now.  I am attempting to follow the guidance given at https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/916/867, which says, "If you really want to know about a particular comment, you can flag the post and ask [the deleting] moderator to tell you." // I had written a comment explaining why I was voting to close.  This is standard practice.  I would like to know why my comment was deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**66 caracteres**

> Ajo y agua. Inclusión a tope. Los moderadores obedecen o largo. Es por vuestro bien

Comment: Muy buena - pero no se si "mods" es válido

Comment: Perdón, pero ¡no conozco la expresión "Ajo y agua"! (por lo que posiblemente un número significativo de lectores queden igualmente excluidos de la comprensión inmediata que el modo sintético debiera garantizar)

Comment: De acuerdo con la observación hecha a 'mods', que es un anglicismo

Comment: @user2325442: "Ajo y agua" es un eufemismo, de a "A jo(derse) y agua(ntarse)". También se usa la variante más larga "Ajo, agua y resina" = "A jo(derse), agua(ntarse) y resina(rse)"

Comment: como anota @user2325442 el *Ajo y agua* suena a ibérico... sin aparición en el DLE, pero ya es el op quien decide

Comment: @walen no se que decirte, la tuya puede ser mas larga pero el ser mas soez casi que es un plus. Fue lo mas gracioso de todo el lío que se armó en SE

Answer (score 23):

#### 135

> Si os molesta, tirad de esta. Se dice el pecador, no el pecado. Tengo muchas bocas que alimentar. Hace falta talante. ¡Mientras moderes bajo mi techo...! Es por el bien de todos.

---

In support of aparente001's efforts to provide English translations for our visitors, here's mine:

> If you don't like it, suck on it*. Hate the sinner, hide the sin. I have many mouths to feed. Willingness is needed. As long as you mod under my roof...! It's for everyone's good.
>
> <sub>*The literal translation for Spanish *"tira de esta"* would be "pull this one" where "this one" in understood to be the (sometimes figurative) penis of the one speaking. However, given that "pull my dick" in English has a totally different meaning, I think the English expression I used is better at conveying both the meaning and the rude tone.</sub>

Comment: Se pueden dar _bounties_ en respuestas que son _community wiki_? Esta es tan buena que se merece mis 37602 puntos. Porque en el fondo, `¡Mientras moderes bajo mi techo...!` es la única parte de todo este asunto sobre la que el individuo puede tomar su propia posición y decisión.

Comment: Me he reído tan fuerte que mis hijos han venido a ver qué estaba viendo en el móvil...

Comment: Ay, me hacia tanta falta reír hoy. ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿5000 puntos de aquí a Navidad? Hold my tea...

Comment: @walen - would you do me a favor and provide a back-translation to English?  I'm having trouble with *tirad de esto* and *talante*.

Comment: @walen - pardon me for asking, but how are *S--- my d---* and *Tira de esto* different?  I'm asking because my son has Tourette Syndrome and the one that starts with S is something I hear a lot at home... just out of the blue in his case.... // How about "It's for your own good" at the end?  People who beat their children tend to say this.  // I don't really understand *talante* so I don't know what to suggest, but "willingness* could maybe be improved upon -- anyway, it's amazing. // Oh, yes, and how does "se dice el pecador"  work?

Comment: @walen - I see, thanks.  Well, this isn't vulgar, but how about "Like it or lump it."

Comment: Podrías ahorrar 4 con "te j****".

Comment: @walen - Related question on ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/514367/112436 -- I'm thinking "Like it or lump it" would be better.  I hesitate to edit it myself.  What do you think?

Comment: @walen - Thanks for helping me understand the idiom better. // "If you don't like it, suck on it" doesn't work in English because "it" has two completely different meanings in the two clauses.  Even taking into account that "tira de esta" has an *implicit* reference to the penis.  But I do see that "like it or lump it" doesn't match the tone of the original.  I will think about it some more.

Comment: @walen - Also note (in case you are ever in a situation that calls for an expression like this in English), I don't think *pull my d---* is a phrase in English.

Comment: @walen - Do you have a link you can share?  I've never heard that phrase -- and I can say, having a 16yo with dysinhibition due to his Tourette's, I've heard a lot....

Answer (score 19):

## <s>219 160</s> 149 characters

> Sí, gente ha molesta por la reciente decisión. Nada diremos, mas nos leen millones, todo sea por la inclusión y el respeto. Nos impondremos por las buenas o por las malas, por el bien común.

---

And now a back-translation to English, for guests who might land on this page:

> Yes, people are upset about the recent decision.  We won't explain anything, even though we are read by millions, it's all for the sake of inclusion and respect.  We will impose our will one way or another.  It's all for everyone's good.

Answer (score 13):

#### 37

> Ni mu decimos porque nos la suda la comunidad.

I mean, the idea of translation is to translate the sentiments, not the actual words, so I think this covers all the grounds fairly well.  If we want the beat-around-the-bush style translated to Spanish, an appropriate translation would be 3x as long as the English ;-)

Here is a rough translation to English:

> You won't get a peep out of us because we're not worried about the community.

The verb *sudársela* is a peninsular expression meaning to not be bothered in the least by something (roughly akin to *sweating something off*, to use the same verb). [Link to RAE's definition of it](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YdJpI2b#FQMumpu).  *No decir ni mu* is an expression that refers to keeping quiet.

Comment: Thanks guifa for removing the offensive bit (which in fact you did not add). We have now undeleted the post and CMs agree on it. These are difficult moments in which everything is happening at the same time on a very high speed, so I suggest people to calm a bit down, take a big breath and try to find their own view on all of this. I am sure SO as a company will provide valuable feedback in the future. In the meanwhile, stick to meta topics in Meta, and use the main site to keep making the Spanish language a bit better. Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99430/discussion-on-answer-by-guifa-translation-golf-xlviii--were-sorry-to-see-you-g).

Comment: Falta el recuento: **37 caracteres**

Answer (score 10):

## 240 characters

> Algunos están enfadados por lo decidido esta semana. No daremos detalles por respeto a los involucrados, pero el sitio llega a millones y queremos fomentar inclusión y respeto. Moderador que lo viola, lo hablamos entre nosotros. Si no, algo haremos. Siempre mirando por el bien de todos los de SE.

---

And now a back-translation to English, for guests who might land on this page:

> Some folks are mad about what was decided this week.  We won't give any details out of respect for those involved, but the site reaches millions and we want to promote inclusion and respect.  Moderators violating this will be spoken to privately.  And if not, we will do something.  Always keeping in mind the good of everyone at SE.

Answer (score 9):

Sucintamente, en **39** caracteres:

> Adiós moderadores, ¡nuestros usuarios primero!

O en **37**:

> Adiós moderadores, nuestros usuarios antes.

*And now in English, for guests who might land on this page:*

> *Adios, moderators, our users come first!*

Acortando a **23** caracteres:

> Moderadores: *¡antes la gente!*
>
> Mods: *The people first!*

Answer (score 7):

**Lamentamos tu partida**

(**108** caracteres)

> La afectación a moderadores, —que entendemos contrariados—, es en pos del respeto e inclusión de millones de usuarios del sitio de SE

And now a back-translation to English, for guests who might land on this page:

> We regret your departure
>   The effect upon moderators —understandably upset— is out of respect and inclusion of millions of SE users.

Comment: gracias @walen, ¡es verdad! (lo hbía tomado del título "We're sorry to see you go")

Comment: @user2325442 - I tried to make a back-translation to English but I don't think I made a very good one -- would you check it, please?

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Comment: *La web* está en el DRAE, y te ahorraría uno respecto a *(de)l sitio*.

Answer (score 6):

### 71 chars

> Os he¹ cabreado². Por respeto, callo, mas las vacas sagradas valen³ ante todos. ¡Por Fulanito⁴!

*And now a back-translation to English, for guests who might land on this page:*

> I've pissed you (plural) off. Out of respect I'll hold my tongue, but sacred cows come before everyone. For all the no-one-specials!

¹ Conste que, según entiendo, la persona que publicó el texto que traducimos es la misma persona que echó a Monica.
² Sentido 2 del DRAE: *coloq. Enfadar o poner de mal humor a alguien.*
³ Sentido 10 del DRAE: *Dicho de una cosa: Prevalecer en oposición de otra*
⁴ O sea, por todos los del montón

Comment: PeterTaylor - oye, ¿cómo sabes que fue la misma persona?  ¿Tienes acaso un enlace?  Eso es algo que yo no he llegado a entender muy bien. // No entiendo este uso de *cabrear*.  ¿Quieres proponer una traducción a inglés?

Comment: @aparente001, si me hubieras preguntado lo mismo hace cinco días igual podría haberte dicho de dónde sacaba esa idea, pero ahora hay tantos hilos y he leído tantas versiones que no me aclaro. Si quieres cambiarlo a *hemos*, cámbialo. Total, no veo ninguna respuesta con entre 72 y 74 caracteres.

Answer (score 5):

## <strike>158 155</strike> 146 characters

(Gracias a @fedorqui por la sugerencia)

> Comprendemos se molesten por nuestras frescas decisiones. Como
>   nos leen millones, haremos lo que queramos para fomentar inclusión
>   y respeto. Si no acatas, pagas. Todo por su bien.

And now a back-translation to English, for guests who might land on this page:

> We understand you might be bothered by our recent decisions. As
>   millions read us, we will do as we like to encourage inclusion and
>   respect. If you don't comply, you'll pay. It's all for everybody's own good.

Answer (score 4):

## 160 characters

> Perdón, no argüiremos el fallo recién por respeto de los dañados. Hay que actuar con inclusión y respeto aquí (hay millones aquí). Aun moderadores. Zanjamos problemas en privado por el bien de todos.

In English:

> Sorry, we're not going to argue about the recent decision out of respect for those hurt. It's necessary to act with inclusion and respect here (there are millions here). Even moderators. We resolve problems privately for the good of all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99431/discussion-on-answer-by-bob-translation-golf-xlviii--were-sorry-to-see-you-go).

Answer (score 4):

**75**

> Por el bien de los usuarios, oíd y obedeced, moderadores: ¡inclusión total o bote<sup>1</sup>! ¡Y sanseacabó!

<sup>1</sup>: De la primera acepción de botar: 1. tr. Arrojar, tirar, echar fuera a alguien o algo.
Podría cambiar el "*¡Y sanseacabó!*" para reducir letras, pero me gusta tanto el patrón de los sufridos padres (y madres) ...

Comment: @walen Si - :-)

Comment: Vuelvo a la versión anterior